# Commas in Compojure routes

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I'm trying to create a route that has a parameter which contains commas in compojure

```
(GET "/tags/multiple/:tag-names" [tag-names] multiple-tags)
```

but for some reason, whenever I include a comma in the `:tag-names` field, it 404s. It works fine when there are no commas.

Does anyone know what causes this and how I can work around it?

Comment: Are you using compojure `andler/api` or `handler/site` to route the request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compojure uses [`clout`](https://github.com/weavejester/clout) for routing. From `clout`'s [`README`](https://github.com/weavejester/clout/blob/master/README.md):

> Clout supports both keywords and wildcards. Keywords (like `:title`) will match any character but the following: `/ . , ; ?`.

By default, `clout` treats commas as path segment separators. You can work around that by passing a custom regex to the route. The following would make `:tag-names` match any character except `/`:

```
(GET ["/tags/multiple/:tag-names" :tag-names #"[^/]+"] [tag-names] multiple-tags)
```